# calculate seconds-to-date for pre-epoch date/times using MS VS2003

Tags: c++, visual-studio, algorithm, datetime

I have this routine that calculates the seconds-to-date for a `struct tm`. On Linux my implementation using mktime works fine, but 
[mktime on windows VS2003/.NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d1y53h2a(VS.71).aspx) 1.1 returns -1 for pre-epoch datetimes.

How do I calculate meaningful time_t values (i.e.

> value + secondsToEpoch == secondsToDatetime

) from a for pre-epoch dates, using ANSI C++ only (no boost, Qt either)?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Can you expand a bit on exactly what you're trying to do? What sort of operations do you need to support?

Comment: Yes, I also have problems understanding what exactly the issue is. The sample code does not make sense without further explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at a couple of mktime sources on the net, they all look pretty portable so you ought to be able to grab one and just put it in your source, paying attention to legal requirements, of course.

That said, I think you have to look for the right one.  What dates are you working with?  If you're working with pre-1970 dates, there's a good chance you're going to need a 64-bit time_t.

There are also some weird calendar changes very early on that might be a concern, e.g., the switch to the Gregorian calendar.

Comment: could you post some links to mktime sources? Thanks.

Comment: I just googled "mktime source" and came up with things like http://www.raspberryginger.com/jbailey/minix/html/mktime_8c-source.html

Comment: According to the request, the requirement was to support pre-Epoch dates (i.e. with a negative number).  The sample code provided returns an unsigned value, so does not support pre-Epoch dates.